# View array while debugging assembly code in visual studio

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, assembly, masm, visual-studio-debugging

I defined a DWORD variable: `arr DWORD 6 Dup(?)` and tried to view this array with visual studio debugger.

I did try `arr, 6`  but it doesn't seem to work while debugging assembly code.

I also tried `arr`, `arr + 1`, `arr + 2` separately but the result is terribly wrong.

[image]

[image]

How to view the entire array?

```
    ReadDec_inline proc Uses eax ebx ecx esi edi, n:DWORD, pArr:DWORD
        Local OldEsp:DWORD
        ; Type in n numbers
        mov eax,10
        mov ebx,n
        mul ebx
        add eax,n
        sub eax,1; add (n-1) space characters
        mov OldEsp,esp
        sub esp,eax
        mov esi,esp
        invoke ReadString,esi,45,offset _dword
    
        ;Now we extract
        mov esi,pArr
        
        mov ecx,n
        
        L1:
            mov eax,0
            W1:
                .If(BYTE PTR[esp + eax] == " " || BYTE PTR[esp + eax] == 0)
                    mov BYTE PTR[esp+eax],0
                    jmp quitW1
                .Else
                    inc eax
                .EndIf
            jmp W1
            quitW1:
            mov edi,esp
            mov ebx,eax
            invoke ReadDec, edi, 1
            mov [esi],eax ; Fetch the number
            add esi,4
            add esp,ebx
            inc esp ; Next number
        loop L1
    
        mov esp,OldEsp
    ret
    ReadDec_inline endp
```

Comment: It's very suspicious to see `inc esp ; next number` in your code. What's that supposed to do, and especially in an array of dwords? Why don't you include the actual program in your question?

Comment: @SepRoland You're right. Something wrong with that particular line. I've actually added a variable OldEsp without noticing. Thank you!

Comment: @SepRoland I store an dynamically allocated array of chars in stack. Esp holds the offset of the array and esi is actually the one who controls the array of DWORDs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> proc Uses eax ebx ecx esi edi
> ```

Because of the `mul ebx` instruction, you should add `EDX` to the list. The result of this multiplication will be in `EDX:EAX`.
Or better, change

> ```
> mov eax,10
> mov ebx,n
> mul ebx
> add eax,n
> sub eax,1; add (n-1) space characters
> ```

into

```
imul eax, n, 10 + 1
dec  eax
```

---

> ```
> invoke ReadString,esi,45,offset _dword
> ```

Shouldn't this hardcoded 45 be actually 65? Same as the calculated value?

---

Your *L1* loop depends on the `ECX` register. I don't think that `ECX` is a call-preserved register, so probably `invoke ReadDec, edi, 1` messes up the count.

```
        mov  esi, pArr
        mov  ecx, n
        L1:
            mov  edi, esp
            push ecx        ; (1)
            xor  ebx, ebx
            W1:
                .If(BYTE PTR[edi + ebx] == " " || BYTE PTR[edi + ebx] == 0)
                    mov  BYTE PTR[edi + ebx], 0
                    jmp  quitW1
                .Else
                    inc  ebx
                .EndIf
            jmp  W1
            quitW1:
            invoke ReadDec, edi, 1
            mov  [esi], eax ; Fetch the number
            add  esi, 4
            pop  ecx        ; (1)
            add  esp, ebx
            inc  esp        ; Next number
            dec  ecx
            jnz  L1
```

> I defined a DWORD variable: `arr DWORD 6 Dup(?)` and tried to view this array with visual studio debugger.

Your `invoke ReadDec_inline, 3, offset arr` asks for just **3** array elements and you can see their values in the *Memory 1* pane. I sincerely thought the issue here was not having specified the whole **6**.

However, it fails in the *Watch 1* pane because Visual Studio allows you to write expressions in the Watch windows. This means that `arr`, `arr+1`, `arr+2`, and `arr+4` are expressions that first retrieve the value at *arr* (the first array element which has the value 13), and then have some constant added.

I don't use Visual Studio myself, but for MASM you could try:

```
arr[0]     or just arr
arr[4]
arr[8]
```

or

```
[arr+0]    or just arr
[arr+4]
[arr+8]
```

Comment: 1. I'm missing "Uses edx". That's a critical mistake! I'll add that in.
2. 10*n + n - 1 is just 11*n - 1. This one is pretty cool.
3. My ecx is preserved after ReadDec is called so we don't actually have to push ecx and pop ecx at the end of the loop.  4. And about the "45", it's another mistake of mine :D. It's supposed to 11*n -  1, which is the value of eax.

Thank you for your notice!

Comment: *Because of the mul ebx instruction, you should add EDX to the list* - should you, though?  More like remove EAX as well, and let the normally call-clobbered registers EAX, EDX, and ECX be clobbered by this function.  You don't want MASM to save/restore EAX around your function, that would overwrite your return value with a `pop eax` magically inserted right before the `ret`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner: Also, if you're going to reserve a variable amount of space on the stack, it's usually good to round that up to a multiple of 16 (or at least 4) bytes to keep ESP aligned.  And instead of saving the old ESP into static storage, use EBP as a traditional frame pointer which you can restore ESP from.  Like GCC and clang do for example: https://godbolt.org/z/sh14Gnxb7.  If you still want to save/restore some other regs like EBX and EDI, https://godbolt.org/z/saMaET1TM shows how compilers manage that, restoring ESP with `lea esp, [ebp-12]` / `pop ebx` / ...

Comment: @Sep: This answer doesn't answer the title question about displaying MASM arrays in Visual Studio's debugger.  I thought it was a debugging-technique question, moreso than about the broken code.  (That's why it didn't originally even show the code, just screenshots.)

Comment: Also, you mentioned using `imul`, but you can actually `imul eax, n, 11` - unlike most x86 instructions, [imul-immediate](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) is fully 3-operand `imul reg, r/m, imm`.  But yeah, absolutely, if you're not going to use the EDX high-half result of `mul`, don't use `mul` in the first place; it's slower and inconvenient.

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you know any ways to display MASM arrays ? If so, please write an answer(I haven't accepted Sep's answer yet). By the way, your advice is helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner: No, I don't use MASM or Visual Studio.  Most debugger have ways to hexdump a range of memory, usually with your choice of element size groupings, (e.g. gdb `x /6wx arr` to dump six 32-bit integers in hex format.)  IDK if MASM generates debug info that would let the debugger know what the size of the array was supposed to be; in asm source it has a `sizeof` operator which other assemblers like NASM and GAS don't, so it's possible that it could communicate that info to the debugger somehow so you don't even need to manually type in the array length.